# Is there a simple systemc channel with a blocking write and read function?

Tags: systemc

I'm looking for a simple channel to use in system-c between sc_modules for the purpose of hardware modelling.

The functionality I'm looking for is basically an sc_fifo with size 0. 
A write should be blocking until the other side does a read.
And a read vica-versa (should block until the other side writes).

I want the functionality as if I would implement a valid/ready handshake with the data I'm transferring trough the port.

Does such a channel exist, and if not what are alternatives I could use. Trying to keep it as easy to use and as little error prone as possible.

I'm not looking to synthesis the code (purely for modelling).

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Michael

Comment: There is no such a channel in SystemC standard library. You will have to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

Cross-posted to the Accellera forums at https://forums.accellera.org/topic/6414-is-there-a-simple-systemc-channel-with-a-blocking-write-and-read-function/.